# How do I launch Firefox with a negative nice value as a regular user?

Tags: sudo, root, nice

I did this

```
sudo nice -n -1 firefox
```

to launch Firefox with higher priority and make all subprocesses that are executed at launch inherit that priority but it failed with an error message about Firefox can't be run as root in a regular user account.

I need `sudo` to use negative nice values but the rest of the command should be run as my regular user.

How can I use negative nice values but still run the program as my regular user?

I don't want to use `renice` on already launched processes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the user allowance to put negative nice values. Look at `/etc/security/limits.conf` or similar and add a line

```
<username>             -    nice            -20
```

to get the job done

Comment: Is this the only way? I don't want to give this permission generally (I will forget to remove it when I don't need it anymore and requiring sudo is a good reminder to prevent entering the wrong value).